# "As Low As" / Expired Special Price Still Showing (Magento 2.1.11)

Tags: magento2, special-price

I have a configurable product with two variations. Each simple product has a special price set as expiring yesterday, and this is properly reflected when the product is added to the cart.

However, "As Low As [special price]" still displays on the product. Is this the intended behavior, or is there a way to fix this? Thanks!

Edit: have of course tried flushing cache/reindexing/etc. Also, some easy bounty for someone to collect, I'd imagine.

Comment: reindex data and flush cache

Comment: Already ran reindexer / flushed cache

Comment: Check the configurable product itself if has an active special price

Comment: @arjus the Configurable products don't have special price settings (at least in M2.1.11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue you need to edit the following file:

> vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Price/LowestPriceOptionsProvider.php

change line 58:
from:

> `->addAttributeToSelect(['price', 'special_price'])`

to:

> `->addAttributeToSelect(['price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date'])`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you provide any more context on this fix and why it would work? Is this a fix to a known bug, etc?

Comment: Confirmed that this works, in terms of not pulling in the special price. "As low as" still shows, up some reason.

Comment: @BrockfastCowboy, don't change directly to the core Magento file, you need to either update the Magento version or override the `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Pricing/Price/LowestPriceOptionsProvider.php` in your module.

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal I know the score, thank ya.

Answer (score 1):

Its a default bug of Magento2.

You can see the GIT commit in the latest version of Magento2.

Reference GIT commit :

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/1ab9b26828cd4da268e9a7481d4969bffb1460c1
```

Upgrade to the latest version of Magento2 will resolve your issue.